# How to have a member function implementation dependent on class' template parameter?

Tags: c++, c++11, enable-if

This is my best attempt:

```
#include <iostream>

template <bool EnableSomething = false>
class MyClass
{
    typename std::enable_if< EnableSomething >::type
        something(int& x)
    {
        x += 1; //do something
    }

    typename std::enable_if< !EnableSomething >::type
        something(int& x)
    {
        // do nothing, should be optimized away
    }

public:
    void Process()
    {
        int x = 0;
        something(x);
        std::cout << "Enabled: " << EnableSomething << ".  x = " << x << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyClass<true> yes;
    MyClass<false> no;
    yes.Process();
    no.Process();
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler says:
`tester.cpp(12): error C2039: 'type': is not a member of 'std::enable_if<false,_Ty>'`

Comment: This seems to be a good case for `if constexpr`, but in c++ 11 you will need to write regular member function templates.

Comment: Firstly, make sure you have `type_traits` included. Secondly, you cannot overload based on the return type.

Comment: This is fundamentally wrong. SFINAE is based on argument deduction and substitution, thus "failure not a error". Here no deduction at all.

Comment: This shoudn't be marked as duplicate, little different question as can be seen from @VT_T's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make regular templates with default argument taken from parent tempalte:

```
template<bool x_enabled = EnableSomething> 
typename std::enable_if< x_enabled >::type
something(int& x)
{
    x += 1; //do something
}

template<bool x_enabled = EnableSomething> 
typename std::enable_if< !x_enabled >::type
something(int&)
{
    // do nothing, should be optimized away
}
```

With c++17 things become simpler:

```
void
something(int& x)
{
    if constexpr(EnableSomething)
    {
        x += 1; //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: With c++17 `something` is not needed. Just do `if constexpr` in `Process()`. `something` is a workaround for lack of `if constexpr`.